# Teradata DDL Comparison Across Servers

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

How can I compare the structure of two tables that are on different servers lets say Dev & QA in Teradata?

Comment: teradata or mysql?

Comment: In Teradata, using any script or any code or any TD utilities

Comment: Using any text editor that allows you to compare files